# Meaning of ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to understand a C program which includes a .h file with the line

```
#define random                  ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))
```

The C program also includes `<math.h>`.

My guess is that this simply produces a random number from a uniform distribution on the interval [0,1]; is this correct?

Comment: Undefined behaviour on all platforms with `int` having no more than 32 bits). Anything can happen, case closed - next please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 1<<31 well defined in C when sizeof(int)==4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268467/is-131-well-defined-in-c-when-sizeofint-4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ostensibly yes. But it's wrong in two principal ways:

1. Use `RAND_MAX` instead. That's what it's there for. It might be much smaller than `1 << 31 - 1`.
2. `1 << 31` will give you *undefined behaviour* on a platform with a **32 bit** `int` or less, which is remarkably common. Don't do that!

Note that if you don't want to ever recover the value 1, (as is often the case), then use `RAND_MAX + 1.0` on the denominator. The `1.0` forces evaluation in floating point: you run the risk of overflowing an integral type if you write `RAND_MAX + 1`.

Comment: It would also invoke UB on platforms with more than 16, but less than 33 bits. And `RAND_MAX + 1` very likely invokes UB on all platforms.

Comment: If you don't mind I've edited the answer. Both are very good points. Thank you.

Comment: But isn't `RAND_MAX + 1.0` a `double` type?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I don't use floating point in my applications (it is most times a very bad idea on embedded systems). You are right. If you ignore the potential performance issue, you can use it. Still the standard random functions don't guarantee any quality of the algorithm. If a true uniform distribution is required, the algorithm should be choosen carefully and - if really - a floationg point range is required, one should use that directly.

Answer (score 5):

The `rand` function returns a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.  This program is assuming that `RAND_MAX` is 2^31 - 1 and is dividing the result by that number.

So yes, if the above assumption is true, then this macro gives a number from [0,1].  It is not so much a uniform random distribution, but rather a "pseudo-random" value.

At least that's what it's *supposed* to do.  This expression `(1 << 31)` invokes undefined behavior (assuming `int` is 32-bit or less) because the the constant `1` has type `int` and left-shifting by 31 puts it outside the range of `int`.  In practice, if two's complement representation is used, some compilers will allow this shift and then the subsequent `-1` will put it back in range, but that can't be depended on.

This undefined behavior can be avoided by using `(1U << 31)`, which makes the constant `1` have type `unsigned int` so that the shift it within range.  A better option is to forget the shift and subtract and just use `0x7fffffff`.

But for maximum portability, it should be defined as follows:

```
#define random ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX)
```

But there's still a problem.  A `float` typically has a 23 bit mantissa.  If `rand` returns a 32 bit value, you won't get a good distribution of numbers.  Better use use `double`, which has a 52 bit mantissa:

```
#define random ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX)
```

Comment: You don't see any UB?

Comment: @Olaf Right.  Added detail on that.

Comment: That shift is problematic - at best. On implementations with less than 32 bits, it still invokes UB (shift count >= bit-width). The `RAND_MAX` approach is better. But using `float` very likely looses precision and limits the ditribution to typically not more than 23 bits (mantissa of IEEE `float`).

Answer (score 1):

> My guess is that this simply produces a random number from a uniform distribution on the interval [0,1]; is this correct?

No.  Code may never return `1.0f` nor uniform results.

`#define random ((float) rand() / (float)((1 << 31) - 1))` has lots of issues.  It is weak code.

---

**Lost of precision**: Typical [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has about 24 bit of precision.  Converting the result of `rand()`, if it exceeds 24 bits, results to a `float` which may differ in value from the original due to rounding.  This weakens/destroys the *uniformity* of the random number generation.  Different `rand()` results will come up with the same answer.  See also [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771436/meaning-of-float-rand-float1-31-1/38773134#comment64915733_38771512)

A fix for this is problematic as OP apparently wants a uniform random number from the set [0, 1/2,147,483,648, 2/2,147,483,648, ... 2,147,483,647/2,147,483,648] which is not possible given the likely precision limits of `float`.

---

The worst, is that `(1 << 31)` is **undefined behavior** UB unless `int` is at least 33 bits long.  Shifting a 1 into the sign position is UB. C11dr §6.5.7 4.

To avoid UB, use `((1ul << 31) - 1)`.

Yet using the magic number `((1ul << 31) - 1)` is not as robust as basing the fraction on `RAND_MAX`.

Further `(float) ((1ul << 31) - 1)` may suffer from loss of precision as described above as it forms the value `2147483648.0f` and not the unobtainable `2147483647.0f`.  OP's code may *never* generate a `1.0f`.

---

I suspect OP really needs a [0..1) result and not [0..1].  Both are below.

```
// generate a `double` in the range [0 ... 1)
#define random0to_almost1  (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))
// or 
// generate a `double` in the range [0 ... 1]
#define random0to1  (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 0.0))
```

Note that this suffers like OP's original code should the precision of `double` (typical 53 bits) is exceeded by `RAND_MAX` needs.

To cope, one mitigating step is to insure `RAND_MAX + 1.0` is done exactly.  In the *extremely common*, but not C specified, `RAND_MAX` is a power-of-2_minus_1.  So `RAND_MAX/2 + 1` is an `int` and an *exact* power of 2.  Conversion of that `int` to `double` is certainly *exact*.

```
#define random0to_almost1  (rand() / (2.0*(RAND_MAX/2 + 1)))
```

---

A `float` solution would be

```
// This value is platform dependent, but very common
// Do not a a highly portable generation method yet.
#define FLT_POWER2_INTEGER_LIMIT (1ul << 24)


#define random0to_almost1  ( \
    (rand() % FLT_POWER2_INTEGER_LIMIT) /  \
    (RAND_MAX % FLT_POWER2_INTEGER_LIMIT + 1.0f) \
    )
```

Comment: Conversion of a power of 2 `int` value to `double` might not be exact if `FLT_RADIX` is not a power of 2.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Yes- agreed.  C allows a `FLT_RADIX` of `2,3,4,5...`  I have yet to come across a `FLT_RADIX` other than `2,10,16`- of course the future may be different.  Certainly values of `2,4,8,16,..` are not an issue with the above answer. With base 10, using the above method still has benefit, but may not reach _exactness_.  Should you know of any non-base 2 systems in use today, would be most interested in hearing of them.